# Mongodb covered query executionStats

Tags: mongodb

Hello i'd like some help understanding the following execution stats.

For this query

```
db.family.find({ "_id" : ObjectId("5c87890b3adcde7da566f0d7")},{_id:1}).explain("executionStats")
```

```
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
```

Specifically not sure why totalDocsExamined is 1 because I would have imagined that sine there is an index on ObjectId, and only that is returned , no documents need to be examined?

Kindly help.

Comment: When _id field is used in the filter condition, the query plan uses a special stage called `"stage" : "IDHACK"`. Few reference  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/RZgz9P2wD3Y  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174345/what-is-plansummary-idhack   https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16891

Comment: Ok but that doesnt explain why 1 doc needed to be examined

Comment: If your query is executed against a sharded cluster (mongos) and _id is not your shardkey, your query would only be only covered when you add also the shardkey to your index.

Answer (score 1):

Your covered query example is hitting a special case optimisation: an equality query on the `_id` index.

Since the `_id` index is always both required and unique, equality queries on `_id`  choose this index and bypass some of the usual stages of query planning and execution. This is a fast path for common queries looking up documents by their primary key.

When this optimisation happens your explain output will include an `IDHACK` input stage and the  detailed `executionStats`will  not show any `rejectedPlans` (since the query planner is bypassed for this path). The `IDHACK` stage always examines the document so won't be a covered query (as at MongoDB 4.2).

The `IDHACK` optimisation is specific to equality queries, so if you want a workaround for a covered query on `_id` you could use a different expression like `$in`:

```
db.family.find({ "_id" : { $in: [ObjectId("5c87890b3adcde7da566f0d7")]}},{_id:1}).
     explain("executionStats")
```

A `$in` query goes through the normal query planning path so other candidate plans will be considered and the explain results will include an `IXSCAN` stage instead of `IDHACK`. This query can also be covered (only index keys examined).